# flink pipeline from kafka to redis

Tags: java, redis, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm using flink to read from kafka and write to redis.

For test, I just want to read the first 10 messages from kafka. So I use a counter and try to stop the consumer when the `counter = 10`

```
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    FlinkKafkaConsumer08<String> kafkaConsumer =
            new FlinkKafkaConsumer08<>("my topic",
                    new SimpleStringSchema() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean isEndOfStream(String nextElement) {
                            // It should only read 10 kafka message
                            return counter.getAndIncrement() > 9;
                        }
                    },
                    properties);
```

but I get 30 message in redis:

```
llen rtp:example
(integer) 30
```

When I change the condition to `counter.getAndIncrement() > 8`, it writes 27 messages to redis. Always triple.

Complete code:

```
public class FlinkEntry {

    private final static JedisCluster JEDIS_CLUSTER;

    static {
        Set<HostAndPort> hostAndPorts = new HashSet<>();
        hostAndPorts.add(new HostAndPort("localhost", 7001));
        JEDIS_CLUSTER = new JedisCluster(hostAndPorts);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        FlinkKafkaConsumer08<String> kafkaConsumer = createKafkaConsumer();
        DataStream<String> dataStream = environment.addSource(kafkaConsumer);

        SinkFunction<String> redisSink = createRedisSink();
        dataStream.addSink(redisSink);

        environment.execute();
    }

    private static FlinkKafkaConsumer08<String> createKafkaConsumer() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        //... set kafka property

        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

        FlinkKafkaConsumer08<String> kafkaConsumer =
                new FlinkKafkaConsumer08<>("my topic",
                        new SimpleStringSchema() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean isEndOfStream(String nextElement) {
                                // It should only read 10 kafka message
                                return counter.getAndIncrement() > 9;
                            }
                        },
                        properties);

        kafkaConsumer.setStartFromLatest();
        return kafkaConsumer;
    }

    private static SinkFunction<String> createRedisSink() {
        return new SinkFunction<String>() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(String value, Context context) {
                JEDIS_CLUSTER.lpush("rtp:example", value);
                JEDIS_CLUSTER.expire("rtp:example", 10 * 60);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you tried to fix the parallelity of your kafka consumer to 1? Just a wild guess ...

Comment: @TobiSH how to do that?

Comment: Try `environment.setParallelism(1);`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I submit the job via web UI, and set parallelism to 1. I think it does the same thing

Comment: What makes you think that FlinkKafkaConsumer08 pays attention to isEndOfStream? I see that Kafka09Fetcher does, but I'm not seeing that in the older version.

Comment: It does care. When I set count to 10, it read 30 message. When I set count to 11, it read 33 message. Always triple... Even I have infinite messages in kafka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to understanding this would be to disable operator chaining by calling

```
    env.disableOperatorChaining();
```

and then look at some metrics -- e.g., numRecordsOut at the source, and numRecordsIn at the sink. I would also double check that the whole job is running with the parallelism set to 1.

You'll need to disable chaining because otherwise the whole job will collapse to a single task, and there won't any metrics collected for the communication between the two operators.